# Laravel blade call route and fetch its data

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am new in blades in Laravel so i would like to ask about, how to call route and fetch it's resonse data?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="app">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
     <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
      Data goes here
      <span class="caret"></span>
     </a>
    </li>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Route endpoint name is:

```
'/api/users/get-user/name -- returns string (name)
```

I have tried:

```
{{ route('users.get-user', ['property' => 'name']) }}
```

But it echos route URL not data.

Comment: I used {{ UserController::get-user('name') }} to get data.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not maken mistake you taken Laravel Blade functionality all wrong. if you need to fetch an data from an api endpoint you should rely on JavaScript (whether frameworks like jQuery, Vue, React etc, standalone libraries for AJAX call like Axios or core js features like fetch api).
Laravel blade has nothing to do with fetch and parse data from remote api endpoint it's helpful for structure and layout of your website.

If you need any help with JavaScript part let me know.